# Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: function, matlab, undefined, cell

I'm using matlab to plot this code which should plot Theta ( dimensionless temperature at different times(t) ), when I try to run it I get this error "Undefined function 'times' for input arguments of type 'cell'"

```
t=1:1:5;
alfa=(1.172.*(10.^(-2))); ......   
    % alfa for steel with 1% carbon = 1.172*10^-2 m^2/s%
L=1;
T={(alfa.*t)./(L.^2)}; % dimensionless time equation %
lambda1=0.3111; % @ biot =0.1 % 
A1=1.0161; % @ biot =0.1 %
theta={A1.*exp(-(lambda1.^2).*T)}; % dimensionless Temperature equation %
plot(t,theta,'.');
```

I'm still a beginner in matlab & programming in general.

Comment: where? when? who? what? D:

Comment: What's this language? This question is missing a language tag.

Comment: Also, it's missing half of the first (and only) sentence

Answer (score 2):

For some reason you're using cell arrays at line 5 and 8 (the curly braces `{}`). Just remove them and your code will plot...

Regards